# How to translate with I18n using active_model_attributes gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-i18n, activemodel

I am using the active_model_attributes gem to define attributes and use validations in classes that do not inherit from ActiveRecord.

I am dealing with the errors when those validations fail. I am raising an exception when the model is not valid like this:

```
unless self.valid?
  raise Lib::Commands::BaseException.new(self.errors.full_messages)
end
```

After that I perform a rescue operation and call a Proc to redirect the user with the error message:

```
rescue ::Lib::Commands::BaseException => exception
  error.call(params[:id], exception.message)
```

The problem is that I need to translate the model attributes name when displaying the error message to the user. I am following [this link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to organize my translation file like this:

```
activerecord:
 models:
  model:
   attributes:
    attribute: ''
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I found the answer to this problem.

The problem is that I was dealing with ActiveModel and not ActiveRecord, and besides that my class is inside some modules. So to make it work I need to do the following changes:

```
activemodel:
 attributes:
  module1/module2/module3/class_name:
   attribute: 'attribute'
```

So when working with modules the definition is like this:

```
module1/module2/module3/class_name:
```

And when working with the active_model_attributes it is necessary to define under activemodel and not activerecord